# Logic on value increment in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created several input boxes with some logic behind. I need to create a logic for only one input box that if it's the first click, it should increment the value from 0 to 2, and then just a normal increment +1. so to make it clear, the addition should be as follows:

0 > 2 > 3 > 4

If the user clicks on the minus, it should reduce by 1 unless it comes to the value of 2 as than the subtraction should be to 0, so to explain its as follows:

4 > 3 > 2 > 0

```js
    $("#1, #2, #3, #4").prop('disabled', true);
    
    $('.add').click(function () {
    
    var value1 = $('#1').val();
    var value2 = $('#2').val();
    var value3 = $('#3').val();
    var value4 = $('#4').val();
    
    var totalValue = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2) + parseInt(value3) + parseInt(value4);
    
    if ( totalValue >= 5){
        $('.add').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
        $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
      }
      
    });
    
    $('.sub').click(function () {
        if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="field1">field 1
        <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
        <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>
    </div>
    <div id="field2">field 2
        <button type="button" id="sub2" class="sub">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="2" value="0" class="field" />
        <button type="button" id="add2" class="add">+</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="field2">field 3
        <button type="button" id="sub3" class="sub">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="3" value="0" class="field" />
        <button type="button" id="add3" class="add">+</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="field2">field 4
        <button type="button" id="sub4" class="sub">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="4" value="0" class="field" />
        <button type="button" id="add4" class="add">+</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are not my boss

Comment: @Mahi, Whats ^^^^^ for?

Comment: @Mahi asking for help doesn't make you a boss, makes you intelligent as knowledge is shared!

Comment: @BombarleyGoku did you even try ?

Comment: @Mahi, yes I did try but its useless posting code that I tried here when it simply breaks the whole jquery document, I would suggest rather than you wasting your time commenting on such posts with such arrogance, you either help people in this community, or just don't bother comment, you're wasting your time and others!

Comment: @BombarleyGoku firstly you asked how to disable if totalvalue>=5 . if it done that you ask this . seems like you will ask question till you will make website like facebook

Comment: @Mahi, OP asked and deleted previous question?

Comment: @Mahi I never asked any previous questions, I used to code from a question that was asked a couple of mins ago yes you're right, but im not the same person!

Comment: @Satpal - no i didnt, i know the rules and I will follow them!

Comment: @satpal yes and he deleted that question.

Comment: @BombarleyGoku so you both guys working on same project ?

Comment: @Mahi - not at all, in a world of 7.5 billion people, i'm sure that there is someone working on similar projects!